# Do you know linux live-cd with sshd enabled by default?

Tags: iso-image, livecd, sshd

please advice a Linux live-CD which has an sshd server enabled by default. I want to use it as rescue and setup for headless servers.

It should get ip by dhcp or fallback to reasonable default ip if no dhcp server in the Lan.

SOLVED!
archlinux installation CD has ssh enabled by default!
look for this: archlinux-2015.01-1-archboot-network.iso

Answer (score 4):

You can build your own livecd for this. SystemRescueCD has instructions for this ( http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_personalize_SystemRescueCd).

SystemRescueCD already starts sshd at boot. There are two things left to do:

- define a root password by passing `rootpass=<password>` in the boot options
- configure the network by either passing `dodhcp` for dhcp or `ethx=<IP>/<CIDR> gateway=<gateway_IP>` for static configuration.

Comment: This did not quite work for me since the firewall configuration of SystemRescueCD rejected the connection. I had to `systemctl stop iptables` before connecting which isn't ideal, particularly in the context of the original question...

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu server has this. But you can do it on any Ubuntu LiveCD by opening terminal and then: `sudo apt-get install sshd` and then `service sshd start`

Comment: live-usb booted on headless computer by untrained personal. Forget about terminal

Comment: ubuntu-server doesnt start silently, stuck on language select

Comment: I think if you hit enter 2 times during boot, it will actually get to login.